# detect 0 values across rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to know how many rows that contain only `0` values using `tidyverse`

My example.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c","d"),
                 x= c(0,0,1,1),
                 y = c(0,0,1,1))
```

All know is use `base R` as below

```
df[apply(df [,-1], 1, function(x) all(x==0)),]
```

Desired output what I want to see

```
ID x y
1  a 0 0
2  b 0 0
```

Any suggestions for me using `tidyverse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `filter` with `if_any` to return rows with any 0 values in numeric columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(if_any(where(is.numeric), ~ . == 0))
ID x y
1  a 0 0
2  b 0 0
```

---

Or may use `across` with `rowSums`

```
df %>% 
   filter(rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)) == 0) > 0)
  ID x y
1  a 0 0
2  b 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just added the outcome that I would like to see, I would like to know they are "a" and "b" for instance.

Comment: Thank you, I just checked it again it worked well.